# Rails API how to send attached images with the Product as response

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to send a response back to a frontend client.

This is the response I am trying to create:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_title": "Some item"
            "images": ["imageurl1", "imageurl2", "imageurl3"]
            // other product info
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_title": "Some item"
            "images": ["imageurl4", "imageurl5", "imageurl6"]
            // other product info
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently it just looks like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_title": "Some item"
            // other product info
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_title": "Some item"
            // other product info
        }
    ]
}
```

My product.rb looks like:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

Is there a way I can include the attached images in the Product object?

I have been messing around myself and I have tried looking on other posts but I have not found a solution that works.

Comment: can you please share the code from which you are creating this response , which gem you are using for uploading images, or any service?

Comment: Images are hosted on an AWS S3 bucket but the response is just created with the render fuctionality in rails. Like `render json: {data: []}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActiveStorage's helpers for linking to files, as described in the [Active Storage Overview Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files).

Example:

```
url_for(user.avatar)
```

Example for a download link with the content disposition set:

```
rails_blob_path(user.avatar, disposition: "attachment")
```

If you are generating your API output from a serializer class or something else besides the controller action, note the section on using the URL helpers from outside of the controller/view context:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(user.avatar, only_path: true)
```

These examples use `user.avatar` but in your example that would be an instance of one of the many `images` on your `Product` model.

It's worth reading the entirety of that guide before deciding how to expose URLs in an API. For example, consider whether you need private/signed/authenticated URLs because by default these methods generate public URLs.